# Files dimensions with tabs or spaces

Tags: file

why a file with tabs is lighter than a file with spaces?

The files contain only tabs (for tabs.txt) and space(for spaces.txt) with the same space used. a tab is 4 spaces (for me), so in the spaces.txt I type 4spaces for tab.
[image]

Comment: It depends on how the file is encoded.

Comment: Your question already contains the answer: `I type 4 spaces for tab`. 1 tab = 1 character - one space = 1 character. The only difference is that the tab character is a bit "wider" than space character (comparing them visually in an editor).

Comment: Thanks @Robert! I thought wrong, for me a tab was 4spaces, not as 4spaces